# Generate Square Mesh, Given an Unordered X, Y and Z Vectors

Tags: matlab

I have three arrays of the same length in Matlab, `X`, `Y` and `Z`. `X(i)`, `Y(i)` and `Z(i)` forms a pair of 3D coordinates.

The issue now is, how to use these three arrays to generate square meshes, as shown below:
[image]

I got the image from [mesh plot](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshz.html;jsessionid=164c9fe7ffbd934e994fb2cafcf5) in Matlab documentation. So obviously `mesh` command is not what I want because it plots the meshes itself in the Matlab program, whereas I need the mesh elements ( along with the coordinates) so that I can plot them out myself in other program, such as C#.

In other words, I am looking for the *mathematical algorithm* to generate the meshes that allows `mesh` command to plot the below looking graph.

**Edit: I realized that my question wasn't clear after a good night sleep. So here's more detail. I generate `x` and `y` vector by using this command `[x,y]=meshgrid[rangex, rangy]`, and then I define a vector z with the function `z(x,y)`. I would have to return a list of square elements ( as shown in the figure below) along with their corresponding `x`,`y` coordinates. So basically I just want to replot the following graph with those data.**

Any ideas?

Comment: Please clarify the question further.  Looking at the divergent answers, I don't think any of us understand what you want yet.

Comment: Here's some of the extra info that you should add to the question to help us help you: the size of the arrays `X,Y,Z`, some sample values of what might be in them, and clarification of what you mean by "element" and "point" (I think by element you are referring to each square in the mesh, and by point you are referring to a set of indices into an array of points which will give you the coordinates of the corners of the square).

Answer (score 2):

What you basically have are 3 matrices:

```
% define x_range and y_range as you wish
[x, y] - meshgrid(x_range,y_range)

z = some_function_of_x_and_y
```

Now you have to reshape these three matrices into row vectors:

```
sizes = size(x)   
x_row = reshape(x, sizes(1) * sizes(2), 1)
y_row = reshape(y, sizes(1) * sizes(2), 1)
z_row = reshape(z, sizes(1) * sizes(2), 1)
```

and another one of indices:

```
indeces = [1:length(x_row)]'
```

and now your list is:

```
result = [indeces x_row y_row z_row]
```

For instance:

```
x_range = [1,2,3];
y_range = [1,2,3];

>> [x,y] = meshgrid(x_range, y_range)

x =

     1     2     3
     1     2     3
     1     2     3


y =

     1     1     1
     2     2     2
     3     3     3

>> z = x+y

z =

     2     3     4
     3     4     5
     4     5     6

>> x_row = reshape(x, sizes(1) * sizes(2), 1);
>> y_row = reshape(y, sizes(1) * sizes(2), 1);
>> z_row = reshape(z, sizes(1) * sizes(2), 1);

>> indeces = [1:length(x_row)]';

>> result = [indeces x_row y_row z_row]

result =

     1     1     1     2
     2     1     2     3
     3     1     3     4
     4     2     1     3
     5     2     2     4
     6     2     3     5
     7     3     1     4
     8     3     2     5
     9     3     3     6
```

Now `result` holds the indeces in the first column, and `(x,y,z)` in the rest of the columns.  You should be able to extract what you want from there.

Answer (score 0):

```
    x = [1 2 3]; 
    y = [11 22 33]';
    [X, Y] = meshgrid(x,y)
X =

     1     2     3
     1     2     3
     1     2     3


Y =

    11    11    11
    22    22    22
    33    33    33
```

Comment: Good idea, but meshgrid doesn't give me a list of Elements and their corresponding points.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities here. If the points actually already forms a regular lattice in the (x,y) plane, and all you need to do is unscramble which points go where, then a sort will solve your problem. Specifically, use sortrows on the (x,y) pairs, and then a reshape applied to z will get the array into the proper shape. Something roughly like this...

```
[xy,tags] = sortrows([x(:),y(:)]);
z = reshape(z(tags),[n,m]);
```

However, if your data is scattered, then you need to use either an interpolation, or a surface fit. GRIDDATA will solve the interpolation problem, although it will only interpolate as far as the boundaries of your data.

[GRIDFIT](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8998), a tool found on the file exchange, will solve the problem of fitting what is essentially a low order spline surface to your data.

Comment: Not sure whether your example works; I don't see how by reshaping the `z` you can generate a list of elements.